# Is there a example of using node modules(ex: fs) in node integration false?

Tags: electron

I am making a electron app but I have trouble using node modules such as fs, console.log..etc in renderer.js when i use node integration false.

I have found electron documentation and another books but I couldn't found related to what i want. Can you give me a example code or books recommendation?

Comment: Plenty of good examples in the official docs: [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)

Comment: Oh i should see one more time thx